# Выборка по нескольким значениям sql

Tags: sql, umi

Есть база данных и в ней таблица с такой структурой. Поле `obj_id` - id товаров. Поле `rel_val` - значения свойств товара(идентификаторы свойств значений товара).

Например. Товар футболка - id 4034. У нее установлено свойство цвет "красный", id этого значения - 7366. Также установлено свойство размер "M", id этого значения - 7387. И т.д.

Соответственно в таблице это выражается так:

```
obj_id - rel_val
4034 - 7366
4034 - 7387
4035 - 7366
4035 - 8051
4035 - 8057
```

Есть задача создания фильтра по свойствам на сайте. Собственно вопрос в том, как составить запрос sql чтобы выбрать товары по нескольким параметрам. Выбрать условно товары у которых цвет - красный, размер - М и стиль - молодежный.
Как реализовать подобный запрос?

P.S. структура таблицы "cms3_object_content" из базы данных cms umi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использую следующий метод для выборки по нескольким параметрам из одного и того же столбца:

```
SELECT obj_id
FROM  tbl WHERE rel_val IN (7366, 7387)
GROUP BY obj_id
HAVING  (COUNT(*) = 2)
```

COUNT(*) = количество аргументов в IN

Выборка будет, если товар соответствует всем параметрам одновременно.

Comment: не работает. возвращает 0 записей.

Comment: having count(distinct rel_val) = 2

Comment: вот так сработало, спасибо вам и stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой подход:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_items` WHERE `id` = 'YOUR_ID'
AND (SELECT count(`id`) FROM `rel_vals` WHERE `item_id` = 'YOUR_ID' AND  `rel_item_id` = 'YOUR_REL_ID') > 0
AND (SELECT count(`id`) FROM `rel_vals` WHERE `item_id` = 'YOUR_ID' AND  `rel_item_id` = 'YOUR_REL_ID_2') > 0
AND (SELECT count(`id`) FROM `rel_vals` WHERE `item_id` = 'YOUR_ID' AND  `rel_item_id` = 'YOUR_REL_ID_3') > 0 

итд..
```

Преимущество подобного запроса в том, что он легко читается и легко составляется.

**Да простят меня гуру sql**

Comment: этот подход не очень удобен. должно же быть более гибкое решение.

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере obj_id — это не id товара, а id объекта товара. И придётся потом по id объекта дополнительно выяснять id товара.
По-этому считаю лучшим использовать API системы.

Если создать в корне php-файл со следующим кодом, то результатом выполнения скрипта станет текст SQL-запроса, требуемого для выборки.

```
define("CURRENT_WORKING_DIR", str_replace("\\", "/", $dirname = dirname(__FILE__)));
require CURRENT_WORKING_DIR . '/libs/root-src/standalone.php';
$pages = new selector('pages');
$pages->types('hierarchy-type')->name('catalog', 'object');
$pages->where('color')->equals(7366);
$pages->where('razmer')->equals(7387);
echo $pages->query();
```

Вообще лучше использовать API для обращения к базе данных, а не прямые запросы, т.к. структура базы может поменяться при обновлении системы.