# Запрос многие-ко-многим с дополнительным условием

Tags: mysql, select, join

Интересно писать код онлайн-кинотеатра. 
Ситуация стандартна:

Таблица 1: films (id, title и т.д.);

Таблица 2: tags (id, tag) - таблица с тегами (1-триллер, 2-комедия и т.д.)

Таблица 3: tags_to_film (tag_id, film_id) (соответствие фильма определенным тегам)
Требуется: извлечь запросом фильмы с **набором соответствующих тегов**. Это получилось:

```
SELECT films.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) AS genre
    FROM films
    INNER JOIN tags_to_film ON films.id = tags_to_film.film_id
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags_to_film.tag_id = tags.id                     
    GROUP BY films.title
```

Осталась последняя преграда - извлечь фильмы по определенному тегу. Например, по запросу `films.ru/genre/триллер` выбираются фильмы с тегом "триллер".
Т. е. нужно расширить вышеуказанный запрос. Не могу сообразить как. Перепробовал where, еще один JOIN, но что-то не выходит...

UPDATE добавил нужную строку, фильмы по заданному тегу выводятся, но остальные теги **не показываются**:

```
SELECT films.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) AS genre
        FROM films
        INNER JOIN tags_to_film ON films.id = tags_to_film.film_id
        LEFT JOIN tags ON tags_to_film.tag_id = tags.id 
        WHERE tags.tag='$tag'                   
        GROUP BY films.title
```

[image: Почти готово, осталось реализовать последний запрос к БД и заняться дизайном]

Comment: Попробуйте использовать HAVING (вот как образец - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424314/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-sql/424323#424323). Я бы поэкспериментирвоала с Вашим запросом, если бы Вы выложили скрипт создания таблиц с данными, ибо вручную у себя создавать времени нет...

Comment: @Ella Svetlaya, но я не могу указать ничего конкретного в HAVING, ведь сначала нужно найти соответствие тегу (например "триллер") его номеру в таблице tags, а затем по этому id делать запрос. В общем, запутался я.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> но остальные теги не показываются

вы же выбрали «показывать только определённый тэг». вот потому других тэгов быть и не может.

а чтобы вы увидели в одном запросе одновременно и «выборку по одному тэгу» и «выборку по всем тэгам», надо добавить ещё парочку *join*-ов —
смотрите третий запрос в прилагаемом примере.

первый из запросов — просто вывод всего, что есть.
второй запрос — всё, что есть, но с группировкой по тэгам.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8170a/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table f (id int, n text);

insert into f values
   (1, 'sql-запросы')
  ,(2, 'программирование')
  ,(3, 'субд')
;

create table t (id int, n text);
insert into t values
   (1, 'ужас')
  ,(2, 'кошмар')
  ,(3, 'жуть')
;

create table ft (f int, t int);
insert into ft values
   (1, 1)
  ,(1, 2)
  ,(1, 3)
  ,(2, 1)
  ,(2, 3)
  ,(3, 2)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select f.*, t.n
 from f
join ft
 on ft.f = f.id
join t
 on t.id = ft.t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8170a/1/0)**:

```
| id |                n |      n |
|----|------------------|--------|
|  1 |      sql-запросы |   ужас |
|  1 |      sql-запросы | кошмар |
|  1 |      sql-запросы |   жуть |
|  2 | программирование |   ужас |
|  2 | программирование |   жуть |
|  3 |             субд | кошмар |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select f.*, group_concat(t.n)
 from f
join ft
 on ft.f = f.id
join t
 on t.id = ft.t
group by f.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8170a/1/1)**:

```
| id |                n | group_concat(t.n) |
|----|------------------|-------------------|
|  1 |      sql-запросы |  ужас,кошмар,жуть |
|  2 | программирование |         ужас,жуть |
|  3 |             субд |            кошмар |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select f.*, group_concat(t1.n)
 from f
join ft ft1
 on ft1.f = f.id
join t t1
 on t1.id = ft1.t
join ft ft2
 on ft2.f = f.id
join t t2
 on t2.id = ft2.t and t2.n = 'ужас'
group by f.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8170a/1/2)**:

```
| id |                n | group_concat(t1.n) |
|----|------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |      sql-запросы |   ужас,кошмар,жуть |
|  2 | программирование |          ужас,жуть |
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я потратил еще 3 часа, чтобы адаптировать ваш пример к своей конструкции, из которых 1 час я потратил на поиск сводящей с ума ошибки - оказывается лишний пробел в запросе может вызвать фатальный error. Какой ужас! Это наука на всю жизнь!