# Сложная SQL выборка по несколько значениям

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется следующий sql запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT product_id
        FROM product_category
        WHERE cat_id = '39'
        )
    AND id IN (
        SELECT product_id
        FROM product_options
        WHERE opt_id IN (
                31
                ,62
                )
        )
    AND STATUS = '1'
    AND activate = '1'
```

Необходимо вывести только те товары из БД, у которых перечислены опции.

Пробовал решение отсюда [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424314/Выборка-по-нескольким-значениям-sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424314/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-sql) но тогда у меня вообще ничего не выводится.

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT product_id
        FROM product_category
        WHERE cat_id = '39'
        )
    AND id IN (
        SELECT product_id
        FROM product_options
        WHERE opt_id IN (
                31
                ,62
                )
        )
    AND STATUS = '1'
    AND activate = '1'
GROUP BY id
HAVING (COUNT(*) = 2)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите комментарий к ответу - `having count(distinct rel_val) = 2`

Comment: @Serg Bocharov, но мне больше подошел не популярный ответ с перечислением AND (SELECT count(`id`) FROM `rel_vals` WHERE `item_id` = 'YOUR_ID' AND  `rel_item_id` = 'YOUR_REL_ID') > 0

Comment: Лучше перепишите WHERE IN на WHERE EXISTS или просто на JOIN - работать будет намного шустрее.

Comment: Так вы group by вынесли во вне а там запись с данным id всегда одна и count() никогда не даст 2. Вам надо объединить два подзапроса в один, и перенести count/having внутрь что то вроде `SELECT *
FROM product where id in(SELECT product_id ... cat_id = 39 AND opt_id IN (31, 62) GROUP BY product_id HAVING count(1)=2) ...`

Comment: @Akina, у меня данных не так уж и много.